# Why is Mondrian pre-aggegating before calculating Average?

Tags: mdx, olap, pentaho, mondrian

I have a super-simple analyzer report, where all I'm doing is calculating the average of a measure. In the schema, it's default aggregation is AVERAGE. The only other aspect of the report is a filter on date, where I restrict it to being within a list of 3 dates.

What's odd is that it appears that Mondrian is actually calculating the average for each date BEFORE averaging those 3 numbers to get the value displayed in the report. This seems very wrong (the report only has that one average displayed - no other fields).

I don't know MDX that well, but below is what I pulled from the mdx log if that helps:

```
With
Set [*NATIVE_CJ_SET] as 'Filter([*BASE_MEMBERS_ActivityDate], Not IsEmpty ([Measures].[AveragePosition]))'
Set [*NATIVE_MEMBERS_ActivityDate] as 'Generate([*NATIVE_CJ_SET], {[ActivityDate].CurrentMember})'
Set [*BASE_MEMBERS_Measures] as '{[Measures].[*FORMATTED_MEASURE_0]}'
Set [*BASE_MEMBERS_ActivityDate] as '{[ActivityDate].[2012-09-01 00:00:00.0],[ActivityDate].[2012-09-02 00:00:00.0],[ActivityDate].[2012-09-03 00:00:00.0]}'
Set [*CJ_COL_AXIS] as '[*NATIVE_CJ_SET]'
Member [ActivityDate].[*SLICER_MEMBER] as 'Aggregate ([*NATIVE_MEMBERS_ActivityDate])', SOLVE_ORDER=-400
Member [Measures].[*FORMATTED_MEASURE_0] as '[Measures].[AveragePosition]', FORMAT_STRING = '#,###.00;(#,###.00)', SOLVE_ORDER=400
Select
[*BASE_MEMBERS_Measures] on columns
From [SQLTestCube1_JustResults]
Where ([ActivityDate].[*SLICER_MEMBER])
```

Comment: It is definately wrong to average an average i'd be surprised if it's doing this. It's more likely it is calculating the totals and then averaging later. Have you proved that the numbers are wrong, i.e. that they are an average of an average and therefore the incorrect value? Or are you just guessing?  Finally; If you're using Analyzer, why haven't you asked Support?

Comment: I've confirmed it.  I have reached out to support and haven't gotten anything useful yet.  But luckily Julian Hyde replied on twitter.  Here is his explanation, but my MDX skills are weak.  Does it basically mean that Analyzer is writing the MDX stupidly?

"MDX works top down. Aggregate and Average functions add a small number of cells. A measure based  on AVG is bottom-up."

Comment: hmm yes, it does sound like analyzer needs to be more intelligent.  I wonder what Saiku does in this scenario. interesting.